# `rm' no se ha encontrado en el PATH o no es ejecutable

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Me encontraba instalando opencv en una raspberry pi3 usando `pip3 install opencv-python` pero al momento de importarlo obtenia el siguiente error `ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` y logre corregirlo instalando estos paquetes:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
```

El problema es que ahora no puedo ejecutar comandos de linux como `ls` o `rm`

He tratado de arreglarlo usando `sudo apt-get --reinstall install coreutils` Pero esto me retorna este error:

```
dpkg: atención: `rm' no se ha encontrado en el PATH o no es ejecutable
dpkg: error: no se ha encontrado 1 programa esperado en el PATH o no es ejecutable
NOTA: El PATH de root debería incluir habitualmente /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin y /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

La verdad me encuentro ya en un loop sin obtener una solucion

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu `PATH`? Es decir, qué ves cuando escribes `echo $PATH`? Tanto como un usuario normal como siendo root.

Comment: esto es con el usuario pi: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` y esto es con root `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: ¿Puedes ejecutar lo siguiente con ambos usuarios? `command -v rm`

Comment: Aun mejor, ejecuta `type -a rm` con ambos y añade la salida a tu pregunta, por favor. Como miraste el PATH de root? Parece que solo hiciste `sudo echo $PATH` cosa que te dará el PATH de tu usuario y no del root. Cual es la salida de `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'` (fíjate que uso `'` y no `"`) ?

Comment: Cuando intentas ejecutar el rm que error te dice? que no encuentra el path o no es ejecutable o te manda otro error, para poder ayudarte ese error, aunque lo mas seguro es que este buscando la ruta de python3.

Answer (score -1):

Tuve el mismo problema y lo conseguí solucionar así:

sudo touch /bin/rm

sudo chmod +x /bin/rm

apt-get download coreutils

sudo dpkg --unpack coreutils*

Link: https://superuser.com/questions/1024702/rm-not-found-in-path-or-not-executable?answertab=votes#tab-top